# Select all cells in a column containing a text not a formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'd like to ask you this question:
I have in column B of my Excel worksheet these cells

- B1: Ciao    / *text*
- B2: stackoverflow    / *text*
- B3: =A1+A3    / *formula (example)*
- B4: Fabio    / *text*

I want to select only B1, B2, B4; in other words I want to select ONLY CELLS OF COLUMN B WHICH CONTAIN A TEXT, NOT A FORMULA

Is it possible do that in a code as:

```
rng = 'I DON'T KNOW'
For Each cella In rng
..
```

Answer (score 2):

Excel has this function built into `SpecialCells`, so you can do this:

```
Set rng = Sheets(2).Range("B1:B4").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
```

Looping through worksheet ranges in Excel is very slow and best avoided

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `.HasFormula` command in a line written more or less as:

`If Not cella.HasFormula Then`

In this case you will need to copy/select (or whatever) the cell, otherwise not. Put this in your for loop and you're done!

Answer (score 0):

```
Columns("B:B").Select

Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Select
```